# How to start new Tilix session with a same directory as the previous session

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I started recently using Tilix. The main feature I'm missing is checking on the current directory. More precisely:

1. I have a session open in `~/projects/a/b/c`
2. From that session I'm starting a new one (eg by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+T`)
3. I would expect that the new session will automatically cd to the current directory (`~/projects/a/b/c`). Instead, every new session starts with home directory (`~`).

Is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 13):

It is a problem with VTE (Virtual Terminal Emulator), the GTK+3 widget Tilix and others terminal emulators use. VTE needs that the script `/etc/profile.d/vte.sh` executes to do some configurations. In some distros like Ubuntu, this script is not executed in non-login shell sessions by default.

You have two options. 1) Enable Login Sessions in Tilix profile settings or 2) Update `.bashrc` to execute `vte.sh` directly.

For the 2) option you should add in the end of your `.bashrc`.

```
if [ $TILIX_ID ] || [ $VTE_VERSION ]; then
        source /etc/profile.d/vte.sh
fi
```

Maybe you will need to create a symbolic link.

```
ln -s /etc/profile.d/vte-2.91.sh /etc/profile.d/vte.sh
```

More info in [Tilix documentation about VTE configuration](https://gnunn1.github.io/tilix-web/manual/vteconfig/).

Comment: thank you, this is the most precise answer I'm looking for.

Comment: you can directly `source /etc/profile.d/vte-2.91.sh`, without the symbolic link. It works also in `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to edit manually the json file that describes your session.

Open the JSON file where you saved your session and check if the directory is filled properly.

In the "`child`" (*a Panel in the UI*) parameter in the JSON file that describes where you want to have the folder entered, just fill the absolute path to the directory you want to see when you start a new session.

In the file, this part is important to do what you want :

```
directory": "/home/shosta/Developpement/go/src/github.com/...",
```

- Is it set up ?

It looks like that in my JSON file, and it works like a charm :

```
{
    "child": {
        "child1": {
IT'S HERE =>"directory": "/home/shosta/Developpement/go/src/github.com/...",
            "height": 997,
            "profile": "2b7c4080-0ddd-46c5-8f23-563fd3ba789d",
            "readOnly": false,
            "synchronizedInput": true,
            "type": "Terminal",
            "uuid": "ddf598aa-1a07-4157-9c1a-a2c1f16a8bac",
            "width": 960
        },
        "child2": {
      OR HERE =>"child1": {
                "directory": "",
                "height": 498,
                "profile": "2b7c4080-0ddd-46c5-8f23-563fd3ba789d",
                "readOnly": false,
                "synchronizedInput": true,
                "type": "Terminal",
                "uuid": "7c53d235-4717-4166-a142-8d0cb90be723",
                "width": 951
            },
            "child2": {
      OR HERE =>"directory": "",
                "height": 490,
                "profile": "2b7c4080-0ddd-46c5-8f23-563fd3ba789d",
                "readOnly": false,
                "synchronizedInput": true,
                "type": "Terminal",
                "uuid": "e3d41dd7-d4e6-4343-b98f-6d9e31396d71",
                "width": 951
            },
            "orientation": 1,
            "position": 49,
            "ratio": 0.49949849548645936,
            "type": "Paned"
        },
        "orientation": 0,
        "position": 50,
        "ratio": 0.5,
        "type": "Paned"
    },
    "height": 997,
    "name": "${title}",
    "synchronizedInput": false,
    "type": "Session",
    "uuid": "d8377bfe-b1f6-4cd5-8a83-af6de2db1a7d",
    "version": "1.0",
    "width": 1920
}
```

---

By the way, I am not using session but autojump.

https://github.com/wting/autojump

It is way faster to move from folder to folder. It learns from the folder you're using and it's faster than anything experienced.

---

And if you want to move open Tilix sessions quickly, you should give this ULauncher a try :

https://ext.ulauncher.io/-/github-brpaz-ulauncher-tilix

---

I hope that helps.